# Apple Vision Image Registration

Tags: swift, coreml, image-stitching, apple-vision, image-registration

I want to stitch images together to make a spherical panorama in an iOS App. I tried doing it with OpenCV but that turned out to be a waste of time since  it almost always crashes when I try to stitch photos of the ceiling or the floor. Also, it takes up a lot of cpu memory.

I just discovered upon going through Apple documentation that Apple Vision has image registration capabilities. Upon spending hours and hours I couldn't figure out how to use it though. The documentation is [terrible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) and there are no usage examples at all whatsoever.

All I really need is a tutorial or a demo or a function that stitches two or more images and I can make my way from there. Any help will be extremely appreciated since my job depends on it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: not really. Ended up losing the contract because of this. Contacted apple developers and they told me that Vision doesn't yet support image registration.

Comment: Even though it is in the documentation? That is not great.